# qtips not displaying properly

Tags: tooltips

After having to restore from database twice b/c of a bug in the qtip module and extreme lack of documentation, I decided to implement the tooltips programmatically and completely bypass the qtip module.

I used js injector to add the js script to every page (footer).

I edited my theme's template.php file to as to include jquery.qtip.min.js and jquery.qtip.min.css (viewed source of page and verified loading)

Under Devel Settings I selected rebuild theme registry every pageload.

But I still get a rather **odd problem:**

In my [JS Fiddle the code works](https://jsfiddle.net/getoprodigy/rqLxmbv2/1/) as it should and the tooltips display properly.

However, when I view the same exact code in my drupal site **only** the speech bubble callout and part of the tooltip displays, not html content at all displays (doesn't work with basic text either).

I had to add a little bit of js to get the original script to work in Drupal, but I use the same script to execute bootstrap tooltips flawlessly.

Here's what's in JS Injector:

```
! function ($) {
$(function () {
    // Grab all elements with the class "hasTooltip"
    $('.hasTooltip').each(function () { // Notice the .each() loop, discussed below
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).next('div') // Use the "div" element next to this for the content
            }
        });
    });
 });  
}(window.jQuery)
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/getoprodigy/rqLxmbv2/1/)

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: That's weird, should've worked. Are you getting any errors from using the browsers "inspect element" and then clicking on "console"? What happens if you remove the `display: none` in css? does the html show up in the bubble? Perhaps the qtip.css file is loading but not the qtip.js file?  Did you embed the .js file correctly?

Comment: The display:none is necessary or the tooltip content is displayed in ckeditor, making editing a pain.  In any case, I went with bootstrap tooltips for moment and will re-visit the qtips at a later date... things to do.